# disable drop down issue in IE6 and IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-6, html-select

I am showing Category and Sub category in a drop down box and I don't want the drop down value of the main category to be selected by any user.

So I applied `disable="disabled"` and it works fine in Firefox, Chrome, and also IE8, but it is not working in IE6 and IE7.

my code:

```
<option value="test" disabled="disabled" >Test></option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is a well documented problem with IE6/IE7.

A quick Google search revealed this potential workaround:
http://www.goodercode.com/wp/disable-select-options-internet-explorer-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achive this in IE. What you can do is to use a little javascript to tell the user that the option is disabled:

```
function check(el) {
  if (el.options[el.selectedIndex].disabled) {
     alert ("This option is not available!")
     el.options.value = '';
  }
}
```

Also check this solution: http://www.lattimore.id.au/2005/07/01/select-option-disabled-and-the-javascript-solution/

Answer (score 0):

You can put "Category" and "Subcategory" into `<optgroup>` like this:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Category"></optgroup>
</select>
```

or

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Category">
    <option>Category 1</option>
    <option>Category 2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

is supported in IE5.5

See http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/optgroup for details.